# R - Reading in specific rows from a file

Tags: mysql, r

Let's say I have multiple files, each with 15,000 rows and 40,000 columns. I have determined in advance that I only need the last 5 rows from each file. (eg. I need rows 14996, 14997, 14998, 14999 and 15000).

In R, I have been looping over each file with read.table() with the "skip" and "nrows" arguments to extract the rows I need from each file without reading the entire file into R. Unfortunately, It takes a long time, with the skip argument, for R to reach the last five rows of a 15,000 x 40,000 table. Is there a easy, quicker way to extract the rows I need? Should I try out mySQL?

Comment: MySQL doesn't have any conception of row numbers, in the sense that your data might be ordered internally in any way which the RDBMS sees fit.  Do you have a column representing the row number?

Comment: I don't have a column representing the row number. However, the second column in each file has unique identifiers that I could potentially use to subset.

Comment: Add an ID column and then do a query restricting to rows 14996 through 15000 in a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I guess the real question here is were you using R because you intend to analyze the data you read there, or were you only using it to extract data?

Comment: I plan to actually analyze the data.

Comment: Also, I cannot add an ID column to the data since I cannot the entire file in due to its size.

Comment: I can give you  a solution in Java if no one else gives you an acceptable R solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will likely be much faster than `read.table()`

```
lapply(files, data.table::fread, skip = 14995L, nrow = 5L)
```

where `files` is your list of file names.

**Update:**  According to your comments, I think you will want to try `gzfile()` in `read.table()`.  You didn't mention whether you used it in your previous attempt.

```
dflist <- lapply(files, function(x) {
    df <- read.table(zz <- gzfile(x), skip = 14995L, nrow = 5L)
    close(zz)
    df
})
```

Comment: I am getting an error message: embedded nul in string: 'àáõ“Ô\003\0IÏøá4ÔZM2Ì' when attempting to use fread.

Comment: fread("sed 's/\\0//g' H:/Data/Data.txt.gz", skip = 14995L, nrow = 5L)

'sed' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Could you elaborate on how I would incorporate sed 's/\\0//g' into fread()?

Comment: I am not familiar with Cygwin. Would I need to install Cygwin then execute sed 's/\\0//g'? I cannot directly implement sed 's/\\0//g' within R? I am sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I don't have a link to the file. However, I do know that the first column consists of "---" for every row. Could this be the problem? Is there a way to skip the first column with fread()? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I wonder if its possible that the error results from the file being in a compressed .gz format? Would that affect fread()?

Comment: Have you used `gzfile()` in `read.table()`?  If not, try `read.table(zz <- gzfile("file.gz"), skip = 14995L, nrow = 5L); close(zz)`.  This is not yet supported by `fread()` https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/717

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user2205537 - np, so did the `gzfile()` with the update help?

Comment: Yes, it did. However, I ended up decompressing the gz files and using fread() directly on the .txt files.